# library plm not able to load/install

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to install package called plm and i am getting the following error. I already have it installed and I am getting some messy error. any suggestions what I should do?

```
  install.packages("plm", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
  > Error in install.packages : Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!

    > library(plm)
     Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
      namespace ‘pbkrtest’ 0.4-2 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.4 is required
       In addition: Warning message:
      package ‘plm’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plm’
```

Comment: You are working with an old version of R that is not one of the maintenance versions. The best step would be to update R. If this is not possible, MS maintains an archive of CRAN that you can go through to find the latest copy that matches your version of R. For example, https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2015-07-31/ will work for version 3.2.1.

Comment: Do you need version 1.6-6 from R-forge? It currently lists the status as "building" so it's not available for download. If you install from CRAN you should get version 1.6-5.

Comment: I use RStudio and I have updated in recently

Comment: @MrFlick , do you have the link to the CRAN? can you paste the code? Thanks!

Comment: Just take off the repos= argument from install.packages and it will default to CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

install.packages("plm", dependencies = TRUE)

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.